# ValueError when trying to fit regression model

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a data set of 1000 observations where x is independent and y is dependent.
When i am trying to fit a simple regression model I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float64')

There are NaN values or missing data in the data set 
and i also tried imputer with mean strategy for missing data (if any).

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


dataset=pd.read_csv('dataset1.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[: , 1].values


from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN' , strategy = 'mean' , axis=0 )
imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 0:1])
x[:,0:1] = imputer.transform(x[:,0:1])
imputer = imputer.fit(y)
y = imputer.transform(y)



from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(x,y , 
test_size=0.3 , random_state=0)


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train , y_train)
```

error msg :-

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float64').

dataset 
 :- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ryl5my2RG2LpyByhQ_qqgVb7ztZeGtie/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters first. This would improve the readiness of your text. Don't link to datasets. Offer us a sample data set directly in the text.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing label in your dataset (row 215 of the y column in the file you linked). To get rid of it you can simply add the following line right after you load the dataset:

```
dataset.dropna(subset=["y"], inplace=True)  # drop any columns with missing labels in place
```

In your code you are currently trying to impute the missing label. This does not make much sense since there is nothing to be learnt from a missing label and the corresponding x value looks suspicious, too. 
But just in case you are wondering, the imputation did not work because you need to reshape your array first:

```
imputer = imputer.fit(y.reshape(-1, 1))
y = imputer.transform(y.reshape(-1, 1))
```